# Issues using Grapes to grab JDBC driver

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, groovy, groovy-grape

I've read a lot of similar posts about using Grapes to load dependencies but everything I try is getting me nowhere. Using:

```
@Grapes([
    @Grab(group='com.microsoft', module='sqljdbc4', version='3.0')
])

class DatabaseTest {
    static void executeSql() {
        def sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:sqlserver://my.server.com:1433;databaseName=SOME_DB;user=USER;password=secret", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")
        def rows = sql.rows("select something from some_table")
        println rows.join("\n")
    }
}
```

I get:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://my.server.com:1433;databaseName=SOME_DB;user=USER;password=secret
```

A common solution for loading JDBC drivers seems to be adding `@GrabConfig(systemClassLoader = true)` but that only gets me the dreaded `No suitable ClassLoader found for grab` error, which is peculiar because it seems like others add the @GrabConfig to *resolve* the no suitable class loader error.

I have also tried using this:

```
static loadGrapes(){
    ClassLoader classLoader = new groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader()
    Grape.grab(group:'com.microsoft', module:'sqljdbc4', version:'3.0', classLoader:classLoader)
    printClassPath(classLoader)
}

static printClassPath(classLoader) {
    println "$classLoader"
    classLoader.getURLs().each {url->
       println "- ${url.toString()}"
    }
    if (classLoader.parent) {
       printClassPath(classLoader.parent)
    }
}
```

which gives me:

```
groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader@740cae06
- file:/C:/Users/me/.groovy/grapes/com.microsoft/sqljdbc4/jars/sqljdbc4-3.0.jar
groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader@23282c25
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@55f96302
- file:/C:/dev/workspaces/utils/bin/
- file:/C:/dev/eclipse/plugins/org.codehaus.groovy_2.4.10.xx-201704192203-e45/lib/groovy-all-2.4.10.jar
- file:/C:/dev/eclipse/plugins/org.codehaus.groovy_2.4.10.xx-201704192203-e45/lib/bsf-2.4.0.jar
- file:/C:/dev/eclipse/plugins/org.codehaus.groovy_2.4.10.xx-201704192203-e45/lib/ivy-2.4.0.jar
- file:/C:/dev/eclipse/plugins/org.codehaus.groovy_2.4.10.xx-201704192203-e45/lib/servlet-api-2.4.jar
- file:/C:/Users/me/.groovy/greclipse/global_dsld_support/
- file:/C:/dev/eclipse/plugins/org.codehaus.groovy_2.4.10.xx-201704192203-e45/plugin_dsld_support/
sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader@1787f2a0
- file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_111/jre/lib/ext/access-bridge-64.jar
- file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_111/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar
- file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_111/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar
- file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_111/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar
- file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_111/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar
- file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_111/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar
- file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_111/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar
- file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_111/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar
- file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_111/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar
- file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_111/jre/lib/ext/sunmscapi.jar
- file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_111/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar
- file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_111/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar
Caught: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

In this example however I can see that the sqljdbc4 JAR is on the classpath. If anyone has insight, that would be great, at this point I've exhausted about every combination of code I can think of to get this to work.

The only way I got this to run was by adding the JAR into my .groovy/lib directory, but I need to execute this from Jenkins which could run on 10 different slave nodes, so I really don't want to have to manually manage this JAR across different servers.

Comment: This question is not related to sql-server, please use tags properly

Comment: @FLICKER It is, the OP is trying to connect to SQL Server, which is relevant for the question.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, when we choose a tag, we actually choose the audience of the question. to answer this question, no SQL Server knowledge needed. so sql server selecting sql-server tag only shows this up in the list of people who are not able to answer and interested to see this question.

Comment: @FLICKER The fact this is about connecting to SQL Server might actually be important (eg if somebody would use a connection string that is incorrect for SQL Server).

Answer (score 2):

In my experience you need both the GrabConfig annotation and a traditional invocation of Class.forName

For example, this is how I load a JDBC driver in standalone Groovy scripts:

```
@GrabConfig(systemClassLoader=true)
@Grab('org.postgresql:postgresql:+')

import groovy.sql.Sql

Class.forName('org.postgresql.Driver')

DB = Sql.newInstance('jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1/', 'postgres', 'postgres')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using the default system class loader, then you must explicitly load a JDBC driver before you can use it. Only JDBC drivers on the default class loader will automatically get loaded by `DriverManager`. In this case, you will explicitly need to load the JDBC driver using `Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")`, or maybe even `Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver", true, classLoader)`